# bootstrap collapse

Tags: html, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку блок открывался, а другие скрывались?

Добавил `data-parent="#block123"` , но не срабатывает.

Что я делаю не так?

```
<div id="block123"> <p><strong>Блоки</strong>
        <button class="btn" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" data-parent="#block123" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Блок 1
        </button>
        <button class="btn" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" data-parent="#block123" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
          Блок 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" data-parent="#block123" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
          Блок 3
        </button>
      </p>
      <div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>блок 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>блок 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>блок 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не понятная структура, больше похоже на табы! Определитесь табы или аккордеон нужен.

Если все же аккордеон:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="block123" id="accordionExample">

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

    <strong class="d-block m-2">Блоки</strong>

    <div id="heading1" class="m-2">
      <button class="btn" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
          Блок 1
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="heading2" class="m-2">
      <button class="btn collapsed" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
          Блок 2
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="heading3" class="m-2">
      <button class="btn collapsed" style="background-color:#ee5d00;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
          Блок 3
        </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample1" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <p>блок 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <p>блок 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <p>блок 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Одна из проблем как раз в `data-parent="#block123"`, для кнопок этот атрибут не нужен + `parent` у Вас с классом `block123`, а не `id="accordionExample"`.

`data-parent="#accordionExample"` задается блокам, которые разворачиваются.

Если табы:

```css
.nav-link {
  background-color:#ee5d00;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 align-items-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <strong class="d-blcok m-2">Blocks</strong>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link m-2 active" id="pills-1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-selected="true">Block1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link m-2" id="pills-2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-2" aria-selected="false">Block2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link m-2" id="pills-3-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-3" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-3" aria-selected="false">Block3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-1-tab">
    <p>Block 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-2-tab">
    <p>
      Block 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-3-tab">
    <p>
      Block 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Со стилями уже сами.

Comment: Извиняюсь , поправил как у меня стоит. Для табов нельзя задать такое условие? Нажимаешь 1 кнопку - открывается блок, нажимаешь 2 - закрывается 1 и открывается 2. Нужно чтобы кнопки шли друг за другом , а не как аккардион вниз.

Comment: @heymukki, добавила пример с табами. И в первом и во втором случае при клике на соответствующую кнопку открывается соответствующий контент, а весь остальной скрывается.